# How do I work with the AST in Irony now?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, irony

I have a grammar that works and parses in the Irony console just fine, but I don't get anything in the AST treeview.  I was following along with the BASIC->Javascript article found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25069/JSBasic-A-BASIC-to-JavaScript-Compiler, but it seems that the Ast stuff has all been moved/removed.   I found the Irony.Interpreter .dll, which has some Ast stuff in it, but it seems all tied up in the Expression sample implementation.

What am I missing here?  I want to walk my tree and generate source code, and I'm not sure where to start.

I've seen some mention of using the visitor pattern, which I'm fine with, but I don't know how to implement it and run it in a way that Irony likes.

Comment: I just switched over to ANTLR, so I guess this is all moot now. So little help, it hurts. Oh well, thanks for any that took the time to look!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the aptly named [Sarcasm](https://github.com/akfish/Sarcasm) project for a reference implementation of a grammar, parser, and AST built on Irony. I found this [blog entry](http://catx.me/2014/02/28/the-making-of-sarcasm-2-ast-generators-and-fun-with-visualization/) by the author to be helpful in building the AST.

The following is a general purpose guide to getting the AST up and running.

1. Define your grammar ([example](https://github.com/akfish/Sarcasm/blob/38f1555b756c30cd66a2bbda523e51db3c6b9033/Sarcasm/Parser/SarcasmGrammar.cs#L9))
2. Create an abstract base class (`MyBaseNode`) deriving from `AstNode` ([example](https://github.com/akfish/Sarcasm/blob/38f1555b756c30cd66a2bbda523e51db3c6b9033/Sarcasm/Ast/SarcasmNode.cs#L38)). Copy/Paste the methods from the example
3. For each terminal and non-terminal create a new class derived from `MyBaseNode` and

   1. Override `Accept` method ([example](https://github.com/akfish/Sarcasm/blob/38f1555b756c30cd66a2bbda523e51db3c6b9033/Sarcasm/Ast/SarcasmNode.cs#L135)):

   `public override void Accept(IMyNodeVisitor visitor) { visitor.Visit(this); }`

   2. Override [`Init`](https://github.com/akfish/Sarcasm/blob/38f1555b756c30cd66a2bbda523e51db3c6b9033/Sarcasm/Ast/SarcasmNode.cs#L363) (mostly on terminals) or [`InitChildren`](https://github.com/akfish/Sarcasm/blob/38f1555b756c30cd66a2bbda523e51db3c6b9033/Sarcasm/Ast/SarcasmNode.cs#L344) (non-terminals) as appropriate. **This is where the AST magic happens.**
4. Add an interface `IMyNodeVisitor` and add a `Visit` method for each class defined in the previous step ([example](https://github.com/akfish/Sarcasm/blob/38f1555b756c30cd66a2bbda523e51db3c6b9033/Sarcasm/Ast/SarcasmNode.cs#L10)):

   `void Visit(MyDerivedNode1 node);`
5. Set the `ASTNodeType` for each of your terminals and non-terminals in your grammar from step 1.

   1. For terminals - ([example](https://github.com/akfish/Sarcasm/blob/38f1555b756c30cd66a2bbda523e51db3c6b9033/Sarcasm/Parser/SarcasmGrammar.cs#L40))

      `MyTerminal1.AstConfig.NodeType = typeof(MyDerivedNode1);`
   2. For non-terminals - ([example](https://github.com/akfish/Sarcasm/blob/38f1555b756c30cd66a2bbda523e51db3c6b9033/Sarcasm/Parser/SarcasmGrammar.cs#L102))

      `var MyNonTerminal2 = new NonTerminal("MyNonTerminal2", typeof(MyDerivedNode2));`
6. In the grammar enable AST creation: ([example](https://github.com/akfish/Sarcasm/blob/38f1555b756c30cd66a2bbda523e51db3c6b9033/Sarcasm/Parser/SarcasmGrammar.cs#L16))

   `LanguageFlags = LanguageFlags.CreateAst;`

Comment: Holy smokes. Sarcasm isn't just a reference implementation, it is `Sarcasm, an EBNF-like DSL that generates Irony`! This is like inception mixed with ouroboros.

Comment: The link to the Sarcasm project is dead.  (Or is that some sort of intentional "who's on first" joke that I didn't get?)

Answer (score 4):

In Irony parsing is done in 2 phases. First it creates a parse tree and then it creates your AST tree.

You are only seeing the first step. In order for Irony to create the AST you can:

1. Tell it how to to map your NonTerminals to AST nodes:

   E.g. looking at the Irony sample grammer ExpressionEvaluatorGrammar we see:

   ```
   var BinExpr = new NonTerminal("BinExpr", typeof(BinaryOperationNode));`
   ```

   Here the we are telling Irony to map the BinExpr NonTerminal to a BinaryOperationNode which is our AST node.
2. Make it generate the AST when parsing:

   When you set this flag the AST tree will be generated when you parse.

   ```
   this.LanguageFlags = LanguageFlags.CreateAst;
   ```

The root of your AST tree will then be:

```
parseTree.Root.AstNode
```

I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22650/Irony-NET-Compiler-Construction-Kit) source a great starting point.